# Can you publish game on multiple sites?

Tags: web, publishing, webapp

Is it normal (or even allowed) to publish games on multiple sites i.e Itch.io, Gog and Humble Bundle.

Specifically in my case I am thinking of web games.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like something you could have answered for yourself trivially by just visiting those sites and noting how many title show up on two or even all three of the above. Please consider doing at least this minimal amount of research in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General rule: YES. You have the copyrights of the game you made? Then you can distribute anywhere you want.

Exception: if you made a contract that gives any publisher/platform the copyright or exclusivity. As of today, none of these platforms (Steam, GOG, Itch) ask for exclusivity. But publishers, if you distribute your game through one of them, usually ask the copyrights of the game. In this case, you are still the author, but you are not copyright holder.

Before submitting your work to any of these sites, or other sites, you should always read their EULA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But as mentioned above, it depends on your [license](https://web.archive.org/web/20100130213717/http://www.flashgamelicense.com:80/view_library.php?page=license-terms) terms if there are any. If plan on posting on gaming websites like Miniclip or Armor games, you'll definitely want to get a license agreement with them. Otherwise if you go onto sites like itch.io or GoG then you are on your own and your success is dependant on luck, how well you can market your game, the game itself, etc.